# PHP variable in WHERE syntax issue :(

Tags: php, variables

So, I am trying to do a simple query which works fine when I put in the URL manually as a string. But when I put it as a variable it doesn't work. I even checked the variable and the variable has the URl in it. Never put a variable in a WHERE statement so not sure if it is an echo thing or what, just that nothing seems to work.

```
$external_result = $facebook->api(
    array(
        'method' => 'fql.query',
        'query' => 'SELECT share_count, 
                           like_count, 
                           comment_count, 
                           total_count 
                      FROM link_stat 
                     WHERE url="{$urlf}";'
    )
);

echo $external_result[0]['total_count'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a difference between **single** and **double** quoted strings in PHP syntax. A single quoted string does not offer variable interpolation. Whereas double quoted strings do allow you to interpolate variables inside string literals. See [the manual on PHP strings](http://php.net/language.types.string) for more details.

Here's what you need to do.

```
$external_result = $facebook->api(
    array(
        'method' => 'fql.query',
        'query' => "SELECT share_count, like_count, comment_count, total_count FROM link_stat WHERE url=\"{$urlf}\";"
    )
);
```

By replacing your single quotes around that string to double quotes you now get PHP to replace `$urlf` with it's actual value.

Answer (score 1):

Single-quoted strings do not allow for variable interpolation:

```
$foo = 5;
echo("This is $foo"); # "This is 5"
echo('This is ' . $foo); #ditto
echo('This is $foo'); # "This is $foo"
echo("This is \$foo"); # ditto
```

I'd recommend looking through some PHP tutorials or picking up a book.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
$external_result = $facebook->api(
    array(
        'method' => 'fql.query',
        'query' => 'SELECT share_count, like_count, comment_count, 
                    total_count FROM link_stat WHERE url="' . $urlf . '";'
    )
);
```

Comment: I tried this but it came up with no value, but the double quotes issue just above fixed it. Hmmmm.

Comment: Its your prerogative to mark any answer as accepted however just to let you know that there is no difference between your accepted answer and mine other than I am using much preferred way of concatenating variable with string in PHP.

Comment: @Neal: Thanks, yes I see, removed curly braces.

Answer (score -1):

Use double quotes if you are going to do something like that.

```
'query' => "
            SELECT share_count, like_count, comment_count, total_count 
            FROM link_stat WHERE url='{$urlf}';
           "
```

Comment: This totally worked but you said don't! Crap. $external_result = $facebook->api(array(
'method' => 'fql.query',
'query' => "SELECT share_count, like_count, comment_count, total_count FROM link_stat WHERE url='{$urlf}';"
));

echo $external_result[0]['total_count'];

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted either. It's a perfectly acceptable answer, which indeed solves the problem.